# change homeAsUpIndicator icon in android kitkat

Tags: android, xml

I tried to change the default icon of HomeAsUpEnabled by editing my styles.xml file. But my icon did't changed. I am working on min sdk version:23. Below is my styles.xml file.

My styles.xml file

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/back</item>
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/back</item>
</style>
```

Comment: "I am working on min sdk version:23" - KitKat is 19, and just `"homeAsUpIndicator"` should work. Are you calling `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` on the support `ActionBar` in your code?

Comment: Sorry I am working on Marshmallow.Yes I am calling setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Toolbar and call toolbar.setNavigationIcon(). See more on toolbar here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html

Comment: But how to make toolbar navigation icon clicable?

Comment: setActionBar(toolbar). The action bar should have setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled to true.